# filtered list item open wrong activity

Tags: java, android

```
        list = new ArrayList<String>();
//videos list
        list.add("Video1");
        list.add("Video2");
        list.add("Video3");
        list.add("Video4");
        list.add("Video5");
        list.add("Video6");

        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,list);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
//opens activities
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) {


                switch (Integer.parseInt((String) adapter.getItem(position))) {
                    case 0:
                        Intent newActivity = new Intent(list_videos.this,Video1.class);
                        startActivity(newActivity);
                        break;

                }
            }
        });

        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String s) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String s) {

                adapter.getFilter().filter(s);

                return false;
            }
        });




    }

}
```

I have created a list-view and on top of that I added a search-bar.

When I use the search-bar, to filter the results... when I click on item 7, instead of opening the specific clicked activity i.e. 7, it always starts from the first one.

Answer (score 0):

You have only one case statement for the switch which is just:

```
case 0:
```

I think you should add the rest of the cases.

I also see that you are trying to parse the integer from the Strings "Video1, Video2 ...etc" in your case you should start from `case 1` since your list's string-integer combination starts from "1" (i.e. Video1).

Comment: Yes now I have fixed it by doing (position == 0) etc, but my problem is that when I do the search, it counts me as 1 not the first item, but the one that is found first in the search list

Comment: CASE 1: when nothing is searched: the first position has the test player1

case 2: when the user searches for test2. Now listview looks for test2 and finds only one instance of this, and searchlist will only have one player and will be in the first position. Since I've assigned a click event based on location, the first row will always lead to Video1

Comment: If it's index is starting from `1` and not `0` just subtract 1 from the parsed string: `Integer.parseInt((String) adapter.getItem(position)) - 1`